# Count total number of viewers on a page who are at a specific GPS location

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, session, geolocation

So, the basic premise is this.

I have a page being designed that gets a users permission to access their GPS location, displays their location on a map and then updates an info window on the map with their current location info and a message.

Currently the message is just a success or failure message letting them know if they are at the correct GPS coords within 50ft (or whatever value I set for that).

What I want to do is as follows.

Count the total number of viewers of this specific page who have arrived at the correct GPS location and when enough people get there, display a message to them.

So, I am assuming I will need to perform an action of some kind within the code that triggers when the person is within the xx ft radius of the specific location and then stores a session or something, then removes it if they move out of the radius, this would get updated every time their GPS location is checked and updated.

Next let's say I need something to happen when X number of people are all at the correct location and viewing the page.

So, I will then need to be able to count the above and see if it is >= X etc.

Then, once X number of people have arrived at the specific location I will need something on the page to change to display a message to them all.

I am using a modified version of the code found here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation

Modified to display the persons coords, accuracy and distanc from a specific location within the info window, instead of just the basic location found message they were using.

While waiting for enough people to arrive I would like that Info Window to display a message stating Y / X people have arrived, so people can see how many more are needed, then once X number of people arrive at said location I would like that info window to change to displaying a congratulations message and some other info.

Eventually I will be modifying this from a single static location and value of X to something I can have multiple of stored in a database and use for different locations, so different people can use it independantly of each other.

Comment: Nice story, what are you stuck with..

Comment: As mentioned, how to record that someone is viewing the page while at the correct location (and remove them if they stop viewing or go out of range) and take a real-time count of how many people are in the right location while viewing, then modifying the contents of the info window on the map when X number of people has been reached.

Comment: For realtime you would need to use websockets to send updated coords, not sure if you can hook into google maps with that but you could use server-sent-events to stream the data back to the map as an out-of-band connection, that solves 2 problems as it will tell you if they are viewing the page and give you their coords. if you need to calculate the distance betweeen the user and X your need to look into the great circle distance algorithm if google does not supply an api for it as your  need to do much of the logic outside the map. The rest is just showing messages in the UI.

Comment: first of all, what GPS format you are getting? How accurate it is. and you want to group by a region, how small or how big is the region?

Comment: Thanks I will do some research into those things, never done anything with websockets before. Currently I have it working for each individual viewer, getting the viewers location, displaying it on the map, calculating if they are within the radius of the location and displaying different messages if they are there or not. Using the code from the above mentioned website and some modifications I added to calculate the distance and check it etc. I just have to tie in the multiple visitor aspect into what I already have.

Comment: I was hoping to be able to do it more simply with sessions and either a mysql or flat file database or something like that to log who is currently there and somehow using a combination PHP, Javascript and AJAX to keep checking if enough people are listed as there yet every time the GPS info is checked.

Comment: Wils, as mentioned I am using the code on the link provided, all I did was add in my own bits of code to create variables containing a set of decimal GPS coords 42.xxxxxx -83.xxxxxx etc. and some Javascript code that checks the current coords against the coords from the variables and calculate how far from it the user is etc.

Comment: Note that if their phone is asleep or the browser/app is backgrounded you will not know they have left. Background Geolocation and the TravelManager would solve this: - https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7Rmd3Rn8_hDNW1zSWRoXzBTclU

Comment: If you make your users log in to your application then you can take a field in the database which indicates whether the user is logged in or not. for eg: isOnline = 0/1;(0-offline/1-online);
As soon as the user logs in his/her status will change to online and as soon as he/she logs out the status will change to offline.
Then set a time interval function using javascript which checks in every specified time that how many users are online and in the radius of the location...